# Getting User in web api controller using Asp.net Identity 2 - User not authenticated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.net Identity 2 in my new MVC 5 project. After much work I was able to implement my own custom user store etc and authenticate my users at log in. However, when I call `User.Identity.Name` inside my Web API controller, the name is always null and the user is not authenticated. I can see the authorization header and cookies in the request object, but no authorization seems to be occurring. If I add an "authorize" attribute, I am denied access.

EDIT:
Here is the OAuthProvider class:

```
public class MyOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    private readonly string publicClientId;
    private readonly Func<UserManager<CustomUser, int>> userManagerFactory;

    public MyOAuthProvider(string publicClientId, Func<UserManager<CustomUser, int>> userManagerFactory)
    {
        if (publicClientId == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("publicClientId");
        }

        if (userManagerFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("userManagerFactory");
        }

        this.publicClientId = publicClientId;
        this.userManagerFactory = userManagerFactory;
    }

    public static AuthenticationProperties CreateProperties(CustomUser user, IEnumerable<string> roles)
    {
        //var roles = string.Join(",", user.Roles.Select(iur => iur.RoleId));             

        IDictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "userName", user.UserName },
            { "userRoles", string.Join(",", roles.ToArray()) }
        };
        return new AuthenticationProperties(data);
    }

    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (var userManager = this.userManagerFactory())
        {
            var user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            ClaimsIdentity cookiesIdentity = await userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            var roles = userManager.GetRoles(user.Id).ToArray();
            AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(user, roles);
            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, properties);

            context.Validated(ticket);
            context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesIdentity);
        }
    }

    public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
    {
        foreach (var property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
        {
            context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        // Resource owner password credentials does not provide a client ID.
        if (context.ClientId == null)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public override Task ValidateClientRedirectUri(OAuthValidateClientRedirectUriContext context)
    {
        if (context.ClientId == this.publicClientId)
        {
            var expectedRootUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri, "/");

            if (expectedRootUri.AbsoluteUri == context.RedirectUri)
            {
                context.Validated();
            }
        }

        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you are doing something wrong when setting the current identity in the login process. Can you paste that section of code into your question? Also, that kind of hosting are you using, OWIN?

Comment: Thanks olif, yes OWIN. I've added the code.